# Do i need to create an add on for my jira instance if i want to create a mobile client for it?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api, jira-agile, jira-rest-java-api

I am planning to create a mobile application and plan to talk to with my JIRA instance using rest api and after digging through rest api for JIRA 6.1.3 , i have a doubt whether do we need to create a plugin for JIRA instance if i want to create a mobile client for it ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you want to talk to JIRA via REST you **don't need JIRA plugin** unless you need to add some REST points for your needs, or store some data in JIRA which plugins can do.

You can also consider creating JIRA addon to serve some nicelooking pages for your mobile that is creating mobile web application instead.